# Making a webscraper when sometimes the information you are trying to scrape is missing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I try to scrape the brands of all the graphics cards on the page, it works for the first 15 but then I get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

# the url we want to scrape and saves it to a variable
url = 'https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=graphics+card&RandomID=551877219014822520210210001440&PageSize=36'

# opens the url and returns a file object
uClient = uReq(url)

# reads the object and returns the html contents as a string
page_html = uClient.read()

# closes the file
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grabs each element with the class of item container and stores in a variable

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-container"})

# scraping the brands of each graphics card from the website

for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
    print(brand)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where it may make sense to catch the [Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) (in your case a `TypeError`)

```py
try:
    something_which_may_raise()
except TypeError:  # specific Exception
    my_code_to_handle_exception()  # maybe do nothing
except Exception as ex:  # generic Exception
    # NOTE you can collect the Exception object here to interact with it!
    print("caught an unexpected Exception: {}".format(repr(ex))
    raise ex  # re-raise that Exception to the calling function
```

For your case, perhaps this is what you're looking for

```py
...
for index, container in enumerate(containers):
    try:
        print(container.div.div.a.img["title"])  # brand
    except Exception as ex:
        print("couldn't read brand from container {}".format(index))
```

Comment: Wow that worked, thank you so much. Question: Why does the use of enumerate() make it work? Doesnt enumerate just produce a counter and the value? e.g. choices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for index, value in enumerate(choices): 
  print(index, value) would produce                                                                                    0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d

Comment: Ah, it's not `enumerate` which is making it work, but some form of either putting the `try/except` within your loop or not re-raising the exception; yes exactly https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Ok i tried it without enumerate and it works, so i think what makes it work is your except statement "except Exception as ex:". Would you explain why this works, what does having the exception argument being ex actually do

Comment: It's almost-certainly either re-raising (my first example does `raise ex`, and simply `raise` will pick the most recent) or wrapping the entire loop body (by mistake?) and then editing over the intermediate code! The `as ex` group assigns the Exception to the _name_ `ex` (can be any name) within the context of the `except` block ([more here, but it may be unpleasantly theory-heavy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#exceptions)).. this allows you to interact with the Exception object [see Python datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)